# Can I develop an iPhone app using java?

Tags: java, iphone

Is it possible to develop applications for the iPhone using Java? And if so, does it allow the use of custom jar files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally the reply was a no.   The Apple agreement used to say that no interpreted/other languages are allowed.  period.

This has since changed and there are several such solutions:

Codename One - focuses on building applications using Java with visual tools and simulators. Open source with a SaaS backend that removes the need for a Mac.

XMLVM - a translator to convert Java bytecode to C/Objective-C. Open source, but requires writing iOS specific code at the moment.

There are also several proprietary solutions but I have no experience with them. E.g. Software AG has a tool called web objects.

Comment: Java isn't an interpreted language. Of course, since you answered this, Java has become explicitly disallowed. :-/

Answer (score 1):

[AlcheMo](http://www.innaworks.com/alcheMo.html) might be worth a look (I haven't had time to investigate it at all yet)