# how to run J2me Apps on iphone ? Anyone can help me?

Tags: iphone, java-me

### how to run J2me Apps on iphone ? Anyone can help me ?

If J2me Apps now can run on Iphone ? or is never ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we run Java applictions on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193524/can-we-run-java-applictions-on-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run J2ME app on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Apple refuses to authorize a Java plateform on iPhone, so it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Not now. You need to convince Steve Jobs. His email address is publicly available; he's known to reply to some of them, more often recently than it was before.