# strictpf in Android from Java Compiler

Tags: java, android, ios, strictfp

I have a physics application I want to mantain the deterministic across platforms with scrictfp (which I use and works nowadays in Windows/Mac/Linux Machines) with J2SE 6.

I need to convert this code to compile on:

-Android

-IOS

Is this strictfp possible in these platforms?

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't run Java, so no.  Android does run Java 8, so j2Se6 would likely be fine, as long as you weren't trying to do the UI in that library (the Android UI is highly different).

Comment: The UI and the java code are decoupled so there is no issue

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the mobile world,
1) for **Android** we can use Java for coding **so your keyword will work just fine**
2) but it **won't work on iOS** as it does not support Java refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193524/can-we-run-java-applications-on-iphone) due to lack of jvm.